# Code runs considerably faster when executed from module instead of ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that find all cells that have a certain formula. The code adds a comment with the formula as the comment text. The cell is then equals the value. When I execute the code in the module directly, it takes about 1 second. If I execute the macro from the developer ribbon, it takes 15 seconds. Has anybody seen this before? I have included the code below, but I'm not sure if that is the issue or not.

```
'Turn off automatic calculations & screen updating significnatly improves performance
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim datacell As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim sheetarray As Sheets
Set sheetarray = wb.Sheets(Array("Fun Discount", "Multiples", "EV Calc", "Beta", "Bandaid", "Company Reference", "Input"))

'First For Loop goes through all sheets in workbook
'Second For Loop identifies all cells with formulas, tests if cell formula contains "companyaddin"
'If it does contain "companyaddin", add comment with formula text as the comment text, save as values

For Each ws In sheetarray
    For Each datacell In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If datacell.Formula Like "*""companyaddin*" Then
            datacell.AddComment datacell.Formula
            datacell.Value = datacell.Value
        End If
    Next datacell
Next ws

'clears object variables, restores automatic calculations & screenupdate
Set ws = Nothing
Set sheetarray = Nothing
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: You mos tlikely want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for review of working code.  This site is more for the specific coding issues, with error codes, etc.

Comment: My apologies. I'll do that.

Comment: i'll take a wild guess and go with the hang-up being on use of the sheet array, rather than looping through an array and setting the sheet name in the loop... use a standard array (arr as variant) and arr = array("sheetname1","sheetname2")... then set ws = sheets(arr(i)) and use *With ws*.   My only rationale for that guess is having had several issues in the past with a sheet array, where several of those sheets had change events, etc., in them, and it really bogged down the system.

Comment: `Like "*""companyaddin*" Then` ...just to be sure, are you looking for text like `"companyaddin`?

Comment: On CR you'll want to include the entire actual macro, and clarify exactly what "in the module directly" stands for.

Comment: BruceWayne, yes that is correct. Mathieu, that is the entire code except for Sub and EndSub

Comment: Why do you have screenupdating = True if you never set it to false? The Last 4 lines are not doing anything useful if this is the only code you have.

Comment: iSpain17, I set it to false in the second line of code shown above